# Android - Starting custom gradle task after build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Using Gradle 7.0.2 with the new Android Gradle Plugin I try to start a copy task which copies a file in the build folder.

The script looks something like this

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withBuildType("debug"), {
        def copyTestTask = tasks.register("copyTest", Copy) {
            from(file('../../local/test.txt'))
            into(buildDir)
            logger.lifecycle("DEST: $buildDir")
        }

//        build.dependsOn copyTestTask

//        tasks.getByPath(':app:processDebugResources')     {
//            it.dependsOn(copyTestTask)
//        }
    })
}
```

The comments are my first tries to add to copy task in my assembleDebug/assembleRelease build. They do not call my copy task.

My questions:

1. What is the correct way to set the dependency to my task?
2. Which build task should depend on my copy job?